# PHP Testing Include files that only output

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

The way we've been developing, many of our PHP files are included only with the expectation that they will output content; no methods are called, etc. My question is, what's the "correct" way to test this with `PHPUnit`? Should I have the `require` placed in the `setUp` so that it waits till then to run, or is that considered bad mojo?

Comment: Can't you use this => http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/testcase-extensions.html#testcase-extensions.output?

Comment: @Alfred I am using that. My question is about the appropriate place to have the `require`.

Comment: Yeah you should do it like that(for now). I think it is even better if you used require_once. But I would also like to point out that output buffering is not how you should write your tests in the future(but I think you already understood that).

Comment: @Alfred Agreed. I don't like having to use `ob`, but until I can do something better, that's where it's at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's about the only way you can test it. I assume you're planning to use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to capture the content produced so that you can check it against expectations.

The best way is probably to refactor your code so as much work as possible is being done in self-contained classes / functions that return results to the caller, suitable for being tested from PHPUnit in a more conventional way.

Comment: Eventually, that refactor is the goal; but we're nowhere near that yet.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is a web application (i.e.: outputs content that requires a browser to be readable), then PHPUnit is integrated with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), which is a Web Application Testing System. It's indeed very useful, especially since it has a Firefox plugin.

You can read more on PHPUnit and Selenium in the [PHPUnit Manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.1/en/selenium.html).

If your templates (i.e.: include files) are used in command line scripts, then use output_buffering and regular expression assertions or regular assertions (i.e.: assertRegExp, assertEquals).